Mailjet return not exactly the number of campaign
I have the problem about Mailjet get campaigns, after I get campaign by $real_campaign = $mj->get(Resources::$Campaign); but it only return 10 records though I just add more than. I also try to post a new campaign but the result is still exactly as the same.
array:10 [▼
  0 => array:22 [▼
    "CampaignType" => 2
    "ClickTracked" => 0
    "CreatedAt" => "2024-06-27T00:16:17Z"
    "CustomValue" => "mj.nl=10869002"
    "FirstMessageID" => 99642142916612309
    "FromEmail" => "hauchung162@gmail.com"
    "FromID" => 6453917149
    "FromName" => ""
    "HasHtmlCount" => 1
    "HasTxtCount" => 1
    "ID" => 7658184996
    "IsDeleted" => false
    "IsStarred" => false
    "ListID" => 10463354
    "NewsLetterID" => 10869002
    "OpenTracked" => 1
    "SendEndAt" => "2024-06-27T00:16:18Z"
    "SendStartAt" => "2024-06-27T00:16:17Z"
    "SpamassScore" => 0
    "Status" => 0
    "Subject" => "Test mail"
    "UnsubscribeTrackedCount" => 0
  ]
  1 => array:22 [▼
    "CampaignType" => 2
    "ClickTracked" => 0
    "CreatedAt" => "2024-06-27T00:55:54Z"
    "CustomValue" => "mj.nl=10868672"
    "FirstMessageID" => 103864267611641594
    "FromEmail" => "hauchung162@gmail.com"
    "FromID" => 6453917149
    "FromName" => ""
    "HasHtmlCount" => 1
    "HasTxtCount" => 1
    "ID" => 7658185006
    "IsDeleted" => false
    "IsStarred" => false
    "ListID" => 10463354
    "NewsLetterID" => 10868672
    "OpenTracked" => 1
    "SendEndAt" => "2024-06-27T00:55:54Z"
    "SendStartAt" => "2024-06-27T00:55:54Z"
    "SpamassScore" => 0
    "Status" => 0
    "Subject" => "Test mail"
    "UnsubscribeTrackedCount" => 0
  ]
  2 => array:22 [▶]
  3 => array:22 [▼
    "CampaignType" => 2
    "ClickTracked" => 0
    "CreatedAt" => "2024-06-27T01:02:09Z"
    "CustomValue" => "mj.nl=10868679"
    "FirstMessageID" => 94857068329212717
    "FromEmail" => "hauchung162@gmail.com"
    "FromID" => 6453917149
    "FromName" => ""
    "HasHtmlCount" => 1
    "HasTxtCount" => 1
    "ID" => 7658185012
    "IsDeleted" => false
    "IsStarred" => false
    "ListID" => 10463354
    "NewsLetterID" => 10868679
    "OpenTracked" => 1
    "SendEndAt" => "2024-06-27T01:02:10Z"
    "SendStartAt" => "2024-06-27T01:02:09Z"
    "SpamassScore" => 0
    "Status" => 0
    "Subject" => "Test mail"
    "UnsubscribeTrackedCount" => 0
  ]
  4 => array:22 [▼
    "CampaignType" => 2
    "ClickTracked" => 0
    "CreatedAt" => "2024-06-27T01:03:48Z"
    "CustomValue" => "mj.nl=10868675"
    "FirstMessageID" => 104427217524379737
    "FromEmail" => "hauchung162@gmail.com"
    "FromID" => 6453917149
    "FromName" => ""
    "HasHtmlCount" => 1
    "HasTxtCount" => 1
    "ID" => 7658185014
    "IsDeleted" => false
    "IsStarred" => false
    "ListID" => 10463354
    "NewsLetterID" => 10868675
    "OpenTracked" => 1
    "SendEndAt" => "2024-06-27T01:03:48Z"
    "SendStartAt" => "2024-06-27T01:03:48Z"
    "SpamassScore" => 0
    "Status" => 0
    "Subject" => "Test mail"
    "UnsubscribeTrackedCount" => 0
  ]
  5 => array:22 [▼
    "CampaignType" => 2
    "ClickTracked" => 0
    "CreatedAt" => "2024-06-27T01:16:32Z"
    "CustomValue" => "mj.nl=10868842"
    "FirstMessageID" => 100768042879416552
    "FromEmail" => "hauchung162@gmail.com"
    "FromID" => 6453917149
    "FromName" => ""
    "HasHtmlCount" => 1
    "HasTxtCount" => 1
    "ID" => 7658185020
    "IsDeleted" => false
    "IsStarred" => false
    "ListID" => 10463354
    "NewsLetterID" => 10868842
    "OpenTracked" => 1
    "SendEndAt" => "2024-06-27T01:16:32Z"
    "SendStartAt" => "2024-06-27T01:16:32Z"
    "SpamassScore" => 0
    "Status" => 0
    "Subject" => "Test mail"
    "UnsubscribeTrackedCount" => 0
  ]
  6 => array:22 [▼
    "CampaignType" => 2
    "ClickTracked" => 0
    "CreatedAt" => "2024-06-27T01:31:55Z"
    "CustomValue" => "mj.nl=10868680"
    "FirstMessageID" => 98516243014696096
    "FromEmail" => "hauchung162@gmail.com"
    "FromID" => 6453917149
    "FromName" => ""
    "HasHtmlCount" => 1
    "HasTxtCount" => 1
    "ID" => 7658185026
    "IsDeleted" => false
    "IsStarred" => false
    "ListID" => 10463354
    "NewsLetterID" => 10868680
    "OpenTracked" => 1
    "SendEndAt" => "2024-06-27T01:31:56Z"
    "SendStartAt" => "2024-06-27T01:31:55Z"
    "SpamassScore" => 0
    "Status" => 0
    "Subject" => "Test mail"
    "UnsubscribeTrackedCount" => 0
  ]
  7 => array:22 [▼
    "CampaignType" => 2
    "ClickTracked" => 0
    "CreatedAt" => "2024-06-27T02:15:28Z"
    "CustomValue" => "mj.nl=10868706"
    "FirstMessageID" => 102175417750407536
    "FromEmail" => "hauchung162@gmail.com"
    "FromID" => 6453917149
    "FromName" => ""
    "HasHtmlCount" => 1
    "HasTxtCount" => 1
    "ID" => 7658185036
    "IsDeleted" => false
    "IsStarred" => false
    "ListID" => 10463354
    "NewsLetterID" => 10868706
    "OpenTracked" => 1
    "SendEndAt" => "2024-06-27T02:15:29Z"
    "SendStartAt" => "2024-06-27T02:15:28Z"
    "SpamassScore" => 0
    "Status" => 0
    "Subject" => "Test mail"
    "UnsubscribeTrackedCount" => 0
  ]
  8 => array:22 [▼
    "CampaignType" => 2
    "ClickTracked" => 0
    "CreatedAt" => "2024-06-27T02:27:34Z"
    "CustomValue" => "mj.nl=10868721"
    "FirstMessageID" => 99079192973947619
    "FromEmail" => "hauchung162@gmail.com"
    "FromID" => 6453917149
    "FromName" => ""
    "HasHtmlCount" => 1
    "HasTxtCount" => 1
    "ID" => 7658185038
    "IsDeleted" => false
    "IsStarred" => false
    "ListID" => 10463354
    "NewsLetterID" => 10868721
    "OpenTracked" => 1
    "SendEndAt" => "2024-06-27T02:27:34Z"
    "SendStartAt" => "2024-06-27T02:27:34Z"
    "SpamassScore" => 0
    "Status" => 0
    "Subject" => "Test mail"
    "UnsubscribeTrackedCount" => 0
  ]
  9 => array:22 [▼
    "CampaignType" => 2
    "ClickTracked" => 0
    "CreatedAt" => "2024-06-27T02:58:21Z"
    "CustomValue" => "mj.nl=10868825"
    "FirstMessageID" => 56013521536099887
    "FromEmail" => "hauchung162@gmail.com"
    "FromID" => 6453917149
    "FromName" => ""
    "HasHtmlCount" => 1
    "HasTxtCount" => 1
    "ID" => 7658185050
    "IsDeleted" => false
    "IsStarred" => false
    "ListID" => 10463354
    "NewsLetterID" => 10868825
    "OpenTracked" => 1
    "SendEndAt" => "2024-06-27T02:58:21Z"
    "SendStartAt" => "2024-06-27T02:58:21Z"
    "SpamassScore" => 0
    "Status" => 0
    "Subject" => "Test mail"
    "UnsubscribeTrackedCount" => 0
  ]
]

As you can see "CampaignCount" => 14 when I call $real_campaign3 = $mj->get(Resources::$Campaignstatistics);
  0 => array:20 [▼
    "AverageClickDelay" => 0
    "AverageClickedCount" => 0
    "AverageOpenDelay" => 0
    "AverageOpenedCount" => 0
    "BlockedCount" => 0
    "BouncedCount" => 0
    "CampaignCount" => 14
    "ClickedCount" => 0
    "DeferredCount" => 2
    "DeliveredCount" => 51
    "HardBouncedCount" => 0
    "OpenedCount" => 20
    "ProcessedCount" => 53
    "QueuedCount" => 0
    "SoftBouncedCount" => 0
    "SpamComplaintCount" => 0
    "TotalClicksCount" => 0
    "TotalOpensCount" => 0
    "TransactionalCount" => 0
    "UnsubscribedCount" => 0
  ]
]

I dont know why mailjet being like that, can anyone please help me with that?

As per Mailjets Documentation, their APIs by default use pagination and return only 10 records. This is customisable though, using the Limit and Offset parameters when making API requests.

Although not explicitly mentioned in the Question, assuming you're using the official php wrapper https://github.com/mailjet/mailjet-apiv3-php, you can pass an array of filters as the second parameter
Hence, to get more than 10 records, say 50, you would do
$filters = [
    'Limit'=>50,  // default is 10, max is 1000
    'Offset'=>0,
];
$real_campaign = $mj->get(Resources::$Campaign, ['filters'=> $filters]);

But increasing the limit would only work upto 1000. In a real world scenario, you would usually use a small Limit and change the Offset until you've got all the records needed.
